# Linear inequality constraints in Matlab

Tags: matlab, constraints

I want to set up a constraint for the radii of an annulus section of a tube that r_o - r_i > .0025 where r_o and r_i are variables are each 1x11 arrays of inner and outer radii along the length of the tube. I've manipulated this to be

> r_o - r_i - .0025 <= 0

How do I set up A and b matrices (to use in fmincon) to solve this inequality?

I'm assuming my b matrix will just be a column vector with each value -.0025, and a length to match the number of r_o variables (11 in this case), but have no idea what to put in matrix A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints in `fmincon` are of the form `Ax<=b`. Any linear inequality constraint can be brought into this form.

You are optimizing over the entire vector `r_i` and `r_o` right? In that case I would set up your optimization vector `x` as something like `x = [r_i, r_o]'`, i.e., a length-22 (column) vector where the first 11 elements correspond to `r_i` and the remaining 11 elements correspond to `r_o`. In this case, you can map `r_i <= r_o - 0.025` into `[eye(11), -eye(11)]*x <= -0.0025*ones(11,1)` which tells you what your `A` and `b` should look like.